# How do i search for specific data in txt file from just ID

Tags: c

So i was able to display the txt file but when i search with a specific vaccine code it display the first line in the txt file. How do i get the specific vaccine from the txt file just from searching its vaccine code ?

this is the data in my `vaccine.txt`:

```
Pfizer      |PF |USA    |2  |50
Sinovac     |SV |China  |2  |18.8000
AstraZeneca |AZ |UK |2  |10.0000
Sputnik V   |SP |Russia |2  |10.0000
CanSinoBio  |CS |China  |1  |10.9000
```

This is my code

```
void searchvac() {
    char code[32];
    int i = 0, option;
    FILE* fptr;
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n\t\t\t Search Vaccine availability");
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");



    printf("\nEnter Vaccine Code: ");
    scanf("%c", code);
    getchar();
    
    fptr = fopen("Vaccine.txt", "r");

    if (!fptr) { perror("Vaccine.txt"); return; }
    char line[200];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr))
        if (strstr(line, code)) {
            printf("\n======================================================================\n");
            printf("Vaccine Name\t Code\t Produce By\tDosage\t Population Recovered\n");
            printf("======================================================================\n");
            printf("%s", line);
            break;
        }
    printf("\nDo you want to search another Vaccine? (Press 1 to continue & any NUMBER to go back) ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    fclose(fptr);
    
    switch (option) {

    case 1:
        searchvac();
        break;

    default:
        menu();
        break;
    }

    
    printf("\n");
    menu();
```

when i input the dosage (which is 2). it will also print all vaccine with 2 dosage. what i want is the user only allowed to input the vaccine code only.

What is wrong from my code can anyone help ?

Comment: 1. `strcmp(line, code)` is used without guaranteeing that valid string (null-terminated sequence of character) is stored to `code`. 2. `scanf("%c", code);` may read the (maybe newline) character that is not consumed by `scanf("%d", &option);` when `searchvac` is called recurcively and it may not work as expected.

Comment: What is "vaccine code" here? How to read and check may depend on that.

Comment: so should i not use charater ?

Comment: vaccine code is the code of the vaccine for example in txt file its astrazenecca (vaccine name), AZ (the vaccine code) so im trying to make the system so it can search the specific vaccine by just inputing the vaccine code

Comment: @ZidaneLeong: Is the vaccine code a single character? Then you can use the `%c` format specifier. Or is it a single word without any spaces in between? Then you should use the `%31s` format specifier. Or is it the contents of a whole line of input? Then you should use `fgets` instead.

Comment: `scanf("%c", code)` will write at most one character into the variable.  Probably you intended to use `scanf("%31s", code)`

Comment: You should use `scanf("%31s", code);` instead of `scanf("%c", code);` to have it read a string. Specifying the maximum number of elements to the length of buffer minus one (for terminating null-character) is important to avoid buffer overrun.

Comment: Unless the line in the file is nothing but the code you are finding, you probably want to use `strstr` instead of `strcmp`, but that will likely lead to false positives.

Comment: ok i solve the problem already but i would like to know why i use 31s and what does it affect my code ?

Comment: The of recursion here is surely an error (certainly ill-advised).

Comment: @ZidaneLeong - Th critical thing to it working was the `%s` rather then `%c` - you are looking for a string, not a single character. The `31` is simply the length of the buffer receiving the string to prevent user input overrunning the buffer.

Comment: @Clifford so now the problem is when i input the dosage of the vaccine it will show the line which have the same input. i just the user to input vaccine code

Comment: You are using `strcmp` which requires equal strings. You haven't shown us your file format but it seems that the file contains more than just the code... in that case `strcmp` is the wrong function to use...

Comment: BTW: `fgets` stores a new line into buffer but `scanf` doesn't. So that's another reason `strcmp` won't work.

Comment: @ZidaneLeong You should [edit] your question and show (a few lines of) the contents of `Vaccine.txt`, some example input you (want to) use, the actual output you get and the expected output. If the data in `Vaccine.txt` is separated by tabs and/or spaces similar to the heading you print, then please explain where there are tabs and/or spaces. Please also specify if there can be spaces embedded in the data fields similar to the heading "Produce By".

Comment: @Bodo ok i edit already

Comment: What is the user supposed to enter to search for the Pfizer vaccine? Should it be `Pfizer` or `PF` or should your program allow both?

Comment: From your example file it is not fully clear how the format of the file is defined and how you want the comparison to work. Assuming you want to enter a code like `PF`, you could either compare the 2 characters at specific positions of the line or you could extract the string between the first and second `|`, strip spaces and then compare it with the code entered by the user. Note that your condition `if (strcmp(line, code)) {` is true if the strings are *not* equal, so I assume your program will always print all lines. I suggest to create a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

`scanf("%c", code);`

will not work, as the `%c` format specifier will only read a single character. However, your code consists of two characters. Therefore, you may want to change it to the following:

`scanf("%31s", code);`

This will read a whole word of input, up to 31 characters (more won't fit into the buffer).

However, for line-based input, you may want to consider using `fgets` instead of `scanf`, as using `scanf` has several disadvantages. See this link for further information:

[A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Another problem is that the line

`if (strcmp(line, code)) {`

won't work, because if the user enters for example `"PF"`

then `strcmp` will compare that string with

`"Pfizer      |PF |USA    |2  |50\n"`

and determine that they are not identical. Therefore, you must first extract the code `PF` from the string from the input file, and only afterwards compare that string to the user input.

EDIT: Meanwhile, you have edited your question to use `strstr` instead of `strcmp`. I don't recommend using that function, because that function may give false positives. For example, if there happens to be a character sequence in another field which matches the code the user entered, then `strstr` will report a match, even if the code in that line is different.

A common way extract individual fields delimitered by a specific character is to use the function [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). However, that function modifies the string by inserting null terminating characters inside it. Since we may want to print out that string later, we do not want to do that. Therefore, I recommend to use [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) and [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead, like this:

```
while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr) != NULL )
{
    char line_code[3];
    char *p;

    //find end of first field
    p = strchr( line, '|' );
    if ( p == NULL )
        continue;

    //make p point to start of next field
    p++;

    //extract code
    if ( sscanf( p, "%2s", line_code ) != 1 )
        continue;

    //compare user-entered code with code from current line
    if ( strcmp( user_code, line_code ) != 0 )
        continue;

    printf("\n======================================================================\n");
    printf("Vaccine Name\t Code\t Produce By\tDosage\t Population Recovered\n");
    printf("======================================================================\n");
    printf("%s", line);
    break;
    }
}
```

Note that for the code above to work, you will have to rename `code` to `user_code` in your program. It does not make sense to have a variable named `code` in your program if your program handles two codes, one user-entered code and one code from the current line of the input file. In order to distinguish these two codes, I use the variable names `user_code` and `line_code` in my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare only a portion of the line, you cannot use `strcmp` to compare the whole line.  But don't do a linear search through the file!  Build a search tree.  If you want to have a balanced search tree, the code can get fairly complicated, but if you're willing to accept a linear search for the worst case (which may happen if you never rebalance the tree) it can be done fairly easily.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <string.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
struct vac {                                                                       
        char name[50];                                                             
        char code[3];                                                              
        char producer[20];                                                         
        int dosage;                                                                
        float recovered;                                                           
        struct vac *child[2];                                                      
};                                                                                 
                                                                                   
                                                                                   
FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);                                 
void * xmalloc(size_t s);                                                          
                                                                                   
static struct vac *                                                                
push(struct vac *h, const struct vac *v)                                           
{                                                                                  
        if( h ){                                                                   
                int c = strcmp(h->code, v->code);                                  
                if( c == 0 ){                                                      
                        fprintf(stderr, "Duplicate entry ignored\n");              
                } else {                                                           
                        h->child[ c > 0 ] = push(h->child[ c > 0 ], v);            
                }                                                                  
        } else {                                                                   
                h = xmalloc(sizeof *h);                                            
                memcpy(h, v, sizeof *h);                                           
        }                                                                          
        return h;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
static int                                                                         
seek(const struct vac *h, const char *code)                                        
{                                                                                  
        if( h ){                                                                   
                int c = strcmp(h->code, code);                                     
                if( c == 0 ){                                                      
                        printf("%s\n", h->name);                                   
                        return 1;                                                  
                } else {                                                           
                        return seek(h->child[ c > 0 ], code);                      
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        return 0;                                                                  
}   

int                                                                                
main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                       
{                                                                                  
        char buf[128];                                                             
        struct vac t = {0}, *h = NULL;                                             
        FILE *ifp = argc > 1 ? xfopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;                       
        while( 5 == fscanf(ifp, " %49[^|] | %3s | %19s | %d | %f",                        
                t.name, t.code, t.producer, &t.dosage, &t.recovered) )        
        {                                                                          
                h = push(h, &t);                                                   
        }                                                                          
        printf("Enter code to search for: ");                                                    
        fflush(stdout);                                                            
        while( scanf("%127s", buf) == 1 ){                                       
                if( ! seek(h, buf) ){                                              
                        fprintf(stderr, "Not found\n");                            
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
                                                                                   
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
FILE *                                                                             
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)                                         
{                                                                                  
        FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :         
                *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;                                     
        if( fp == NULL ){                                                          
                perror(path);                                                      
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return fp;                                                                 
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void *                                                                             
xmalloc(size_t s)                                                                  
{                                                                                  
        void *rv = malloc(s);                                                      
        if( rv == NULL ){                                                            
                perror("malloc");                                                  
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return rv;                                                                 
}
```